# Grails Domain object triggering save of reference object when saved in Bootstrap

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm getting the following error from my bootstrap file when trying to run my Grails application:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.example.MyObject] with identifier [1]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.example.MyObject#1]
```

..which is strange because there's only one place in the bootstrap where the object itself is being created and saved. The stacktrace points to a line in my bootstrap where another object referencing `MyObject`, lets call it `MyReferencingObject` is being created and saved. `MyObject` isn't modified, however, and nor are there any hooks in the domain object that references it that make modifications to it. There are also dozens of other objects being created that reference the same `MyObject` without causing issues.

I put a `beforeUpdate` method in `MyObject` that prints its stacktrace to see what was causing it to be updated. There end up being two calls, one from the first creation of `MyReferencingObject` and the second call from the second creation of `MyReferencingObject`, which results in the stale object exception.

Why is hibernate triggering an update on `MyObject` when `MyReferencingObject` is created? Why isn't this happening for any other domain objects?

Comment: Without the actual (or test versions that produce the error) Domain classes, this will be difficult to determine the issue.  I suggest maybe turning on sql logging to see what SQL is generated during each save.

Comment: Show us source code of selected frgament of Bootstrap and Domain class; it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: Association is probably saved because https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/orm/hibernate/AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy and `autoRetrieveAssocations()` method. the reason for your error is probably unsafe/invalid usage of hibernate, so without source code it is hard to tell